# Connecting to a MongoDb in Node.js Error

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Quite simply, I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB via Node.js:

```
Db = require('../v2/node_modules/mongodb').Db
Connection = require('../v2/node_modules/mongodb').Connection
Server = require('../v2/node_modules/mongodb').Server

console.log "before"
DbServer = new Server("localhost", 27017, {})
db = new Db("twitter", DbServer, {native_parser:true})
console.log "after"
return
```

That's my code and it's as simple as it gets. My output, however, seems to stop at the `db = new Db...` line.

[image]

It never gets to the after. It doesn't give an error either. I know I have a DB running and when I fire up MongoHub, it's there along with the `twitter` database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the native_parser=true  would be ok

`Native bson parser not compiled, please compile or avoid using native_parser=true`